# DTO for Spring and AnjularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, controller, dto

I wand to process the request from AngularJS. So I have DTO-class:

```
public class LoginDTO {
    private String login;
    private RoleEnum role;

    //setters and getters
}
```

Controller on backend:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/EmployeeService/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/userInfo")
    @ResponseBody
    public LoginDTO currentUserInfo(){
        LoginDTO loginDTO = new LoginDTO(RoleEnum.ROLE_ADMIN, "test");
        return loginDTO;
    }
}
```

And controller on frontend:

```
app.controller("test", function($scope, $http){
    var response = $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "/EmployeeService/user/userInfo"
    });
    response.success(function (data) {
        alert("ok");
    });
    response.error(function(data){
        alert("failed");
    });
});
```

And at the frontend I see `failed`. If I change controller on backend:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/EmployeeService/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/userInfo")
    @ResponseBody
    public String currentUserInfo(){
        return "test";
    }
}
```

I see `OK`. How to use DTO class?

On brawser error `the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)`
and

```
The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with 
characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

Comment: What is the value of the `Accept` request header? It should be something like `application/json`. If it is, try changing the annotation to: `@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/userInfo", produces="application/json")`

Answer (score 0):

Let's add:

```
app.controller("test", function($scope, $http){
    var response = $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "/EmployeeService/user/userInfo",
<!--ADD--!>
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json'
<!--END--!>
    });
    response.success(function (data) {
        alert("ok");
    });
    response.error(function(data){
        alert("failed");
    });
});
```